# So i just started learning python through python docs and i came across a piece of code to print fibonacci series

Tags: python-3.x

code source (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)
Code

```
1    def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
2        a, b = 0, 1
3        while a < n:
4            print(a, end=' ')
5            a, b = b, a+b
6        print()
7    fib(2000)
```

Can anyone pls explain what does print function does here in line 6. Thanks....

Comment: It prints a newline. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print statement in the line 6 has nothing to do with functionality of the code to print the Fibonacci series but it just changes the position of the cursor to the next line, so that next print statement in the same script would be executed in next line. Requirement for this arises because in the print statement of line 4 we have changed the default value of optional argument of print statement from end='\n' to  end=' '. '\n', is the newline character which represents the cursor has been moved to new line.